# Regular Expression Name and Surname

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I need to validate first and last name from Credit card.
For example: "Lange Norton" or "LANGE NORTON"
I use this code:

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"^[A-Z][a-z]*[\pL\pM\p{Nl}][A-Z][a-z]*$"; 
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex]; 
return [nameTest evaluateWithObject:nameSurname];
```

And I have a problem with whitespace. 
"Unknown escape sequence '\p'"
What should I do?

Comment: I am not familiar with the \p escape sequence either, what is the \p supposed to do?

Comment: See here for why its a bad idea to validate people's names: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853346/how-to-validate-human-names-in-cakephp/3853820#3853820 (but that said, if credit cards have rules about the names they'll accept then you'll obviously be fine to stick to those rules)

Comment: @Joe The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) was the first place I found. (Yes, this is Objective-C but, I know :) .)

Comment: Names on credit cards can contain characters other than letters. Mine contains a dot, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you missed some curly brackets

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"^[A-Z][a-z]*[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nl}][A-Z][a-z]*$";
```

if you also need whitspace add `\s`

You can find a list of those properties (the `\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nl}` stuff) [**here on regular-expressions.info**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

> \p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language
>
> \p{M} or \p{Mark}: a character intended to be combined with another
>   character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).
>
> \p{Nl} or \p{Letter_Number}: a number that looks like a letter, such
>   as a Roman numeral.

Additionally I don't think your expression is correct.

Your string needs to start with `[A-Z]` followed by `[a-z]*` (can also be zero) and then only one of those `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{Nl}]` another uppercase ASCII letter followed by lowercase letters.

What happens if the persons name is "René Müller"?

Answer (score 1):

You should find the correct escape sequence that will match whitespaces.
Try `\s` instead of `\p`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got `\p` as an escape sequence, but as the error says, it's not valid.

[EDIT] actually, it *is* valid, but not in the way you're using it.

The correct escape sequence for whitespace is `\s`. This matches any valid whitespace character (there are quite a number of them, not just normal spaces).

However since you're validating only ASCII characters anyway, you could just as easily use a regular space character - ie no escaping required; just press the space bar on your keyboard. That is a perfectly valid character to match in a regex string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
([^\s]+)\s([^\s]+)(.*)
```

Don't forget to escape the \s in objective-c:

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"([^\\s]+)\\s([^\\s]+)(.*)";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
return [nameTest evaluateWithObject: nameSurname];
```

This checks for [anything not a space], then [a space], then [anything not a space], then [anything]

Wont work with name such as "宮本茂"

Will include names written like "John Smith (lots of spaces) Jr"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Spudley, but if you insist on validating the name, you should allow for several names on the card. This will validate for an unlimited number of names.

```
[\sA-Za-z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb `\p{L}` - it means any character from Unicode letters, but I don't know, does your regex engine support this.

Answer (score 0):

There is really a lot more to name validation than crafting a regex. Here's a PHP natural name parser:

[nameparser](http://code.google.com/p/nameparser/downloads/list)

If I can't find an Objective C port, I'll do it my self and post it here.

**EDITED 2/7/2013:**

Here's my port for your coding pleasure:

[NameParser.h](http://pastebin.com/JgwKY8Ag)

[NameParser.m](http://pastebin.com/yRVYfBa4)