# JavaScript variable less than 4 characters

Tags: javascript, variables

I have "name" JavaScript variable. If variable "name" contains less than 4 characters I want to execute line: `msg('name','Your name must contain minimum 4 characters.')';`
I have tried something like this but it interpretated mathematical. Any idea? Thank you.

```
if(name < 4 ) {
  msg('name','Your name must contain minimum 4 characters.');
  return false;
}
```

Comment: How is `name` declared? Probably `name.length` is what you're after, if `name` is a string variable.

Comment: Find a good javascript language reference site.  That will help you with simple issues like this, PLUS you can learn a lot more by getting familiar with the language.

Comment: So `Abe`, `Joe` and `Ron` isn't welcome?

Comment: nor are Ian, Bob, Jon, Ann....... in fact, if we're talking about validating names at all, you might want to read the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853346/how-to-validate-human-names-in-cakephp/3853820#3853820

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if (name.length < 4) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to check the *`length`* of the string, not the numeric value of the string itself:

```
if(name.length < 4) {
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(name.length < 4) {
    //Do something
}
```

You have to check the `length` of the variable.

### [image: Fun facts:]

- `length` can also be used to check the length of an `Array`
- `\n` (new line) is also counted as a character.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of “character”, all answers posted so far are incorrect. The `string.length` answer is *only* reliable when you’re certain that only BMP Unicode symbols will be entered. For example, `'a'.length == 1`, as you’d expect.

However, for supplementary (non-BMP) symbols, things are a bit different. For example, `''.length == 2`, even though there’s only one Unicode symbol there. This is because [**JavaScript exposes UCS-2 code units as “characters”**](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding).

Luckily, it’s still possible to count the number of Unicode symbols in a JavaScript string through some hackery. You could use [Punycode.js](http://mths.be/punycode)’s utility functions to convert between UCS-2 strings and UTF-16 code points for this:

```
// `String.length` replacement that only counts full Unicode characters
punycode.ucs2.decode('a').length; // 1
punycode.ucs2.decode('').length; // 1 (note that `''.length == 2`!)
```