# Accept accents in a PHP form

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

In my form, i do some verifications before registering in database

```
    if( isset($form['lastname']) && !empty($form['lastname']) && !preg_match ('/[^a-z]/i', $form['lastname']))

{

}
```

this does not accept accents like "benoît" or "hélène"

Does anyone know to make them allowed ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Omit the `prey_match` check? What is it for? What do you want to allow and what do you want to disallow?

Comment: Greetings i want to disallow numbers

Comment: Only numbers? What about "!"? Or "$"? Or "風"?

Comment: It also doesn't accept `O'Brien` or `Reece-Jones`, or any number of other valid names. And that's just common English names. Bottom line: Don't even attempt to validate people's names. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853346/how-to-validate-human-names-in-cakephp/3853820#3853820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[French accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_alphabet), as same as [German Umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut) etc. are words **beyond A-Z**.

If you need to filter numbers (0-9), you can use smth. like this (not recomended).

```
if( isset($form['lastname']) && !empty($form['lastname']) && !preg_match ('/[^0-9]/i', $form['lastname'])) {

}
```

Comment: The question is: can you be certain that no-one has a name that contains a digit? *Absolutely* certain?? Sure, John Smith III may use roman numerals for his name, but that's just convention; what's to stop someone else deciding to use "The 3rd" instead?